# error when trying to concatenate data from a xlsx sheet with a string

Tags: python

let's begin with my code, then I'll explain my issue

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row =1, max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        a.write('a string"' + a.write(str(cell.value)))
```

i know for a fact that the data i'll be reading is an integer, so that's why I believe this piece of code is getting the error bellow

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

But I want python to read the data on the xlsx as a string, even tough they are just numbers, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi, you need to convert the value you received into a string, you can't concatenate strings and numbers.

Comment: Why are you calling `a.write` within another `a.write()`? Did you want `'a string' + str(cell.value)`? Or better `a.write(f'a string {cell.value}')`?

Comment: What is `a` ? Might that `a.write()` calls return an `int`, like Pythons method [`file.write('abc') == 3`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns the number of characters written as int.

Comment: it would help to know what `a` is!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row =1, max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        a.write('a string"' + str(cell.value))
```

I think you just need to remove the nested `a.write()`. You have the right idea in casting it to a `str` if you want to concatenate it.

If you're using python 3.6 you can use f-strings instead:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row =1, max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        a.write(f'a string"{cell.value}'))
```

Note, if `cell.value` is `1`, this will result in `a string"1`. This is how you've written it although it might be a typo.